# Reactjs: Unexpected token '<' Error

Tags: reactjs

i am just starting with Reactjs and was writing a simple component to display 

`li` tag and came across this error:

> Unexpected token '<'

I have put the example at jsbin below
http://jsbin.com/UWOquRA/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Please let me know what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 72):

I solved it using **type = "text/babel"**

```
<script src="js/reactjs/main.js" type = "text/babel"></script>
```

Comment: That's correct, use "text/babel" instead of "text/jsx". Reference the babel core url -> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.min.js

Answer (score 31):

**UPDATE:** In React 0.12+, the JSX pragma is no longer necessary.

---

Make sure include the JSX pragma at the top of your files:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
```

Without this line, the `jsx` binary and in-browser transformer will leave your files unchanged.

Comment: But <script type="text/jsx"> is

Comment: using babel I had to throw in `type="text/babel"`. Brave new world of javascript

Comment: this helped in my circumstances: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460420/babel-loader-jsx-syntaxerror-unexpected-token?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 31):

The issue **Unexpected token '<'** is because of missing the babel preset.

Solution: You have to configure your webpack configuration as follows

```
{
  test   : /\.jsx?$/,
  exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
  loader : 'babel',
  query  : {
    presets:[ 'react', 'es2015' ]
  }
}
```

here .jsx checks both .js and .jsx formats.

you can simply install the babel dependency using node as follows

```
npm install babel-preset-react
```

Comment: There's nothing in the question indicating that the original poster is using babel.

Comment: He said he is just starting with Reactjs , for React babel preset have to be use.May be the webpack configuration missed the babel preset

Comment: There's nothing in the question indicating the the original poster is using webpack either. Neither of those are required for working with React although they are both handy.

Comment: @Nuwa thank you. `npm install babel-preset-react` solved my problem.

Comment: if you have `.babelrc` file in the project just `"presets": ["env", "react", "es2015"]` and that's it!!

Comment: I have experience some alternative way that cause this issue, normally there is a index.html file to embed the react bundle file like

<script src='./bundle.js'></script>

but we are not emphasis the type, it will gives the same error log.So good to define the file type also.

<script src='./bundle.js' type='text/jsx'></script>

@julestruong

Comment: If the error occurs in a self-made node_module that I have installed, do I have to do this in my installed module or in the project that I have installed this module?

Answer (score 24):

in my case, i had failed to include the type attribute on my script tag.

```
<script type="text/jsx">
```

Answer (score 8):

I have this error and could not solve this for two days.So the fix of error is very simple.
In body ,where you connect your `script`, add `type="text/jsx"` and this`ll resolve the problem.

Comment: can you also give an explanation for your answer?

Comment: I think when you give type="text/jsx" you worn compiler to know what type of document or file this is.

Answer (score 7):

You need to either transpile/compile that JSX code to javascript or use the in-browser transformator

Look at http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html and take note of the `<script>` tags, you need those included for JSX to work in the browser.

Comment: Yes i know, below is the updated jsbin 
[link](http://jsbin.com/UWOquRA/5/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: That jsbin seems to have their own way of executing the JS, the error is from within their code.

Comment: But it is the same error and at same line number. Also, is there any other reason why such an error will happen if i am using the same code as provided in the [link](http://jsbin.com/UWOquRA/5/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9st5Q/ here is your code in a jsfiddle, where React works fine.

Comment: Seems to me there is something wrong with the 0.8 version as it gives me this error again and again. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: its not wrong in React, its jsbin that reads the textarea and evaluates the code, React-transformer does not get a chance to transform it.

Comment: But it happens with my local file to. Even if i run as plain html file or as a nodejs app

Comment: make sure you set the **type="text/jsx"** in `<script type="text/jsx">` tag, if you want please paste your whole code into a hastebin.org paste

Comment: I was using the starter kit that's when i started having problem. Just now i changed to cdn js files and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working example from your jsbin:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//fb.me/react-with-addons-0.9.0.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main-content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

jsx:

```
<script type="text/jsx">
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var LikeOrNot = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
      return (
        <p>Like</p>
      );
    }
});

React.renderComponent(<LikeOrNot />, document.getElementById('main-content'));
</script>
```

Run this code from a single file and your it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Check if .babelrc is inside your application root folder, not inside a subfolder.  if that's the case move file to root.

Answer (score 2):

if we consider your real site configuration, than you need to run ReactJS in the head

```
<!-- Babel ECMAScript 6 injunction -->  
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
```

and add attribute to your js file - type="text/babel" like

```
<script src="../js/r1HeadBabel.js" type="text/babel"></script>
```

then the below code example will work:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're like me and prone to silly mistakes, also check your package.json if it contains your babel preset:

```
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "env",
      "react",
      "stage-2"
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

For correct tag parsing you'll need to use this babel version : https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.js  and attribute "type='text/babel'" in the script. Besides, your custom script should be within   "body" tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can use code like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

var LikeOrNot = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'Like',
    render: function () {
      return (
        React.createElement("li", null, "Like")
      );
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(<LikeOrNot />, document.getElementById('main-content'));
```

And don't forget add `<div id='main-content'></div>` into the `body` in your `html`

But in your package.json file you should use this dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
...
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
...
}
"devDependencies": {
...   
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.7",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "jsx-loader": "^0.13.2",
...
}
```

It's work for me but i used webpack also, with this options (into webpack.config.js):

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { 
        test: /\.jsx?$/,         // Match both .js and .jsx files
        exclude: /node_modules/, 
        loader: "babel-loader", 
        query:
        {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code. I have added reference to React and React DOM. Use ES6/Babel to transform you JS code into vanilla JavaScript. Note that Render method comes from ReactDOM and make sure that render method has a target specified in the DOM.
Sometimes you might face an issue that the render() method can't find the target element. This happens because the react code is executed before the DOM renders. To counter this use jQuery ready() to call the render() method of React. This way you will be sure about DOM being rendered first. You can also use defer attribute on your app script.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='main-content'></div>
<script src="CDN link to/react-15.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="CDN link to/react-dom-15.1.0.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

JS code:

```
var LikeOrNot = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
      return (
        <li>Like</li>
      );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<LikeOrNot />,
                document.getElementById('main-content'));
```

Answer (score 1):

heres another way you can do it
html

```
<head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
     <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

index.js file with path src/index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import "./styles.scss";

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Hello test</h1>
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

use this package.json will get u up and running quickly

```
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html --open",
    "build": "parcel build index.html"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "16.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.57.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-native": "0.57.13",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.6.1"
  },
  "keywords": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, besides the `babel` presets, I also had to add this to my `.eslintrc`:

```
{
  "extends": "react-app",
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although, I had all proper babel loaders in my .babelrc config file. This **build script with parcel-bundler** was producing the unexpected token error < and mime type errors in the browser console for me on manual page refresh.

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "parcel build ui/index.html --public-url ./",
    "dev": "parcel watch ui/index.html"
 }
```

Updating the build script fixed the issues for me.

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "parcel build ui/index.html",
    "ui": "parcel watch ui/index.html"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help,this worked for me in production.
In your package.json file
add **homepage : address to your webpage**
just like the code below

```
"name": "client",
"version": "0.1.0",
"homepage": "abc.org", 
"private": true,
```

Answer (score 0):

For all those beginners who are trying to understand the concept but blown their mind in loading react without html script injection

here is my completed PR:
https://github.com/tarunvella/react-learning/pull/3

hope this helps everyone that using webpack we can achieve bootstrapping react in root index.js with a index.html placed in public folder with your desired html node

everything is controlled by the bundler , so the bundler will inject the script tag from

```
<script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.582af011.js"></script>
```

in head

below is how index.html body looks like in public folder during development

```
  <body>
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="react">React not rendered</div>

<!-- excluding html script injection -->

<!-- 
<script
crossorigin
src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"
></script>
<script
crossorigin
src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"
></script> -->
<!-- <script type="module" src="app.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="/Client/public/core.js"></script> -->
```

Answer (score -1):

I just started learning `React` today and was facing the same problem. Below is the code I had written.

```
<script type="text/babel">
    class Hello extends React.Component {
        render(){
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>Hello World</h1>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Hello/>
        document.getElementById('react-container')
    )


</script>
```

And as you can see that I had missed a comma (,) after I use `<Hello/>`. And error itself is saying on which line we need to look.

[image]

So once I add a comma before the second parameter for the `ReactDOM.render()` function, all started working fine.