# babel-loader jsx SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm a beginner in React + Webpack.

I found a weird error in my hello world web app.

I'm using babel-loader in webpack to help me convert jsx into js, but it seems like babel can't understand jsx syntax.

Here are my dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.0.14",
  "babel-loader": "^6.0.0",
  "webpack": "^1.12.2",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^1.12.1"
},
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^0.14.1"
}
```

Here is my `webpack.config.js`

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: ['webpack/hot/dev-server',path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/main.js')],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
      loaders: [
          { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"}
      ]
  }
};
```

Here is my `app/main.js`

```
var React = require("react");
React.render(<h1>hello world</h1>,document.getElementById("app"));
```

And this is the error message

```
ERROR in ./app/main.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: ~/**/app/main.js: Unexpected token (2:13)
  1 | var React = require("react");
> 2 | React.render(<h1>hello world</h1>,document.getElementById("app"));
    |              ^
at Parser.pp.raise (~/**/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/location.js:24:13)
```

Thanks for you guys.

Comment: That comma after the `<h1>` looks a little peculiar...

Comment: For newer versions of react , use the new babel modules : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53927457/6665568   . It has better error messages and supports new features of react.

Answer (score 471, accepted):

Add "babel-preset-react"

```
npm install babel-preset-react
```

and add "presets" option to babel-loader in your webpack.config.js

(or you can add it to your .babelrc or package.js: http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/)

Here is an example webpack.config.js:

```
{ 
    test: /\.jsx?$/,         // Match both .js and .jsx files
    exclude: /node_modules/, 
    loader: "babel", 
    query:
      {
        presets:['react']
      }
}
```

Recently Babel 6 was released and there was a major change:
https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/29/6.0.0

If you are using react 0.14, you should use `ReactDOM.render()` (from `require('react-dom')`) instead of `React.render()`: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/#changelog

**UPDATE 2018**

Rule.query has already been deprecated in favour of Rule.options. Usage in webpack 4 is as follows:

```
npm install babel-loader babel-preset-react
```

Then in your webpack configuration (as an entry in the module.rules array in the module.exports object)

```
{
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['react']
        }
      }
    ],
  }
```

Comment: Another question, if i want to use ES6 Syntax in future, should I install babel-preset-es2015 and do some options in config file in the same way?

Comment: You got it. `presets:['es2015','react']`

Comment: I'm trying to follow this but I still get the error. Could you post a complete package.json, and webpack.config.js, main.js "hello world"?

Comment: @dranxo https://github.com/helols/so-hello-world

Comment: @dranxo did you find a solution? I've tried everything on this page and still have the same error

Comment: I didn't. Ended up using a lower version of React

Comment: @dranxo @baylee I noticed an error in this solution. The test only works for files ending in '.js'. So if your file ends in '.jsx', it won't match. The regex should actually be: `test: /\.jsx?/`   This would match both .js and .jsx files.

Comment: I've edited the regex in the answer, so hopefully it'll get accepted. I'm guessing a lot of people use the .jsx file extension, so this will probably help them.

Comment: I don't know why, but seemingly the order matters in: presets:['es2015','react'] I was trying it with presets:['react','es2015'] and it failed

Comment: @Corstin Boerman  your edit is not very good, you don't say what the change is and what its impact is

Comment: I was missing `.babelrc` because it was in the .gitignore of my project for some reason.

Comment: This should now be: `presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']`

Comment: @nnyby your presets array did not work, do you have other suggestions?

Comment: In my case, I had to use presets: ['@babel/react'] instead ['react']. Thanks to you I solved my problem

Answer (score 104):

I ran into a similar issue when migrating from babel 5 to babel 6.

I was just running babel to compile the **src** to **lib** folder `babel src --out-dir lib`

I will share my setup for babel 6:

Ensure you have the following babel 6 **devDependencies** installed

```
"babel-core": "^6.7.6",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0"
```

Add your **.babelrc** file to the project:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]
}
```

Comment: The need for es2015 when using stage-0 was a great catch.

Comment: Was getting an error for unknown syntax at `export App from './App'` - realized I needed stage-0, thanks for this.

Comment: I have an example setup for react, babel and webpack [here](https://github.com/StevenIseki/react-webpack-example) it also includes enzyme for testing css modules and universal rendering.

Comment: this worked for me without stage-0

Comment: It works for me.  I did not have stage-0 in devDependencies.

Comment: I had to put it in webpack.config.js. In the array module.rules, where it says "loader: 'babel-loader', i added this: query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0']
        }

Comment: I ran into this problem the stage-0 was the trick in my webpack config.

Answer (score 40):

Since the answer above still leaves [some people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33509770/react-babel-webpack-not-parsing-jsx-code) in the dark, here's what a complete webpack.config.js might look like:

```js
var path = require('path');
var config = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/main.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query:
            {
                presets:['es2015', 'react']
            }
        }]
    },

};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 26):

For me the solution was to create the file `.babelrc` with this content:

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-1"]
}
```

Answer (score 23):

The following way has helped me (includes react-hot, babel loaders and es2015, react presets):

```
loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react']
      }
]
```

Comment: This helped me when I was following the Django plus React stuff in this link: http://owaislone.org/blog/webpack-plus-reactjs-and-django/
This is (I presume) an alternative to using a .babelrc file as mentioned above.

Comment: this also helped me even though my error is not the same as the original question.

Comment: I had to delete '?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react'. Adding 'state-0' into .babelrc helped to fix problem.

Answer (score 2):

For those who still might be facing issue adding jsx to test fixed it for me

```
test: /\.jsx?$/,
```

Comment: literally for days I've been trying to resolve this with every conceivable change to gulpfile.js, ...and it was this simple

Answer (score 1):

This works perfect for me

```
{
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    query: {
        presets: ['es2015','react']
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a really good boilerplate made by Henrik Joreteg (ampersandjs) here: https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/hjs-webpack

Then in your `webpack.config.js`

```
var getConfig = require('hjs-webpack')

module.exports = getConfig({
  in: 'src/index.js',
  out: 'public',
  clearBeforeBuild: true,
  https: process.argv.indexOf('--https') !== -1
})
```