# Unexpected token - React babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am new to the world react and I have a bug that will not let me progress. This is my webpack

```
module.exports = {
entry: [
'./src/index.js'
],
output: {
path: __dirname,
publicPath: '/',
filename: 'bundle.js'
},
module: {
 loaders: [{
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'babel'
 }]
}
resolve: {
 extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
},
devServer: {
 historyApiFallback: true,
 contentBase: './'
}
};
```

This is my code js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import SearchBar from './components/search_bar';

const API = '';

const App = () => {
 return (
     <div>
         <SearchBar />
     </div>
 );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

This is error
https://gyazo.com/be83135be6f0e7b8ca0c2852536c792f

I tried this solution but it does not work
[babel-loader jsx SyntaxError: Unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460420/babel-loader-jsx-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

This is a project https://github.com/jmrosdev/Practicas/tree/master/React/youtube-search

Bye and thanks!

Comment: For newer versions of react , use the new babel modules : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53927497/6665568  . It has better error messages and supports new features of react.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It fails because Babel doesn't recognize the JSX syntax. So you need to install a babel preset or two:

`npm install --save-dev babel-preset-react babel-preset-es2015`

Create the .babelrc file at the root of your project if you don't already have one. It should have this content

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

Comment: I love it when adding a simple root file fixes weird bugs :) Thanks!

Comment: What is so strange is that I was running npm start for a while with no problems, and then started getting this error. Fortunately, your fix worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and the reason was that **type="text/babel"** was missing:

```
 <script src="./index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely not using the babel-react preset.

Make sure you have it in your dependencies, in your `package.json` file (if you don't have it do `npm install babel-core babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react -D` ) and in the `loaders` section of your `webpack.config.js` make this line

```
    module: {
     loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel'
     }]
    }
```

into this

```
module: {
 loaders: [{
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'babel'
 },
{
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }

}]
```