# Using gulp, webpack, and the babel-loader: Fails to compile jsx

Tags: webpack, vue.js, babeljs, jsx, vue-tables-2

**UPDATE**: [vue-tables-2](https://github.com/matfish2/vue-tables-2) is now served pre-compiled, so no loaders are needed. For the `templates` option it is recommended to use scoped slots, which also don't require any special settings

I'm using gulp, webpack, and the babel-loader to build some files (vue-tables-2):

```
gulp.task('scripts-vue-tables', function() {
    gulp.src('node_modules/vue-tables-2/index.js')
        .pipe(webpackstream({
                output: {
                    path: __dirname,
                    filename: "vue-tables-2.js",
                    library: 'VueTables2',
                    libraryTarget: 'var'
                }
            }
        ))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/vendor/vue-tables-2/js/'));
}
```

In `webpack.config.js` I have included:

```
loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ["latest", "react", "stage-0"],
                plugins: ["transform-vue-jsx"]
            }
        },
    ]
```

And included the same in `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["latest", "react", "stage-0"],
  "plugins": ["transform-vue-jsx"]
}
```

But, running the `scripts-vue-tables` task yields the error:

```
Module parse failed: \node_modules\vue-tables-2\lib\template.jsx Unexpected token (15:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

Note: In general, I have tried to follow the steps outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460420/babel-loader-jsx-syntaxerror-unexpected-token).

Comment: Are you sure `webpackstream` will attempt to read `webpack.config.js`? I'd have expected you to have that config inside your gulp task.

Comment: Thanks! If you turn this comment into an answer, I will mark it as the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`webpack.config.js` is the file read if you use the webpack CLI interface, but in your Gulp example usecase, it will not be used. You'd probably want something like

```
    .pipe(webpackstream(Object.assign({
        output: {
            path: __dirname,
            filename: "vue-tables-2.js",
            library: 'VueTables2',
            libraryTarget: 'var'
        },
    }, require('./webpack.config')))
```

to load both the Webpack configuration *and* the special `output` logic.

Comment: vue-tables-2 is now served pre-compiled, so no loaders are needed. For the templates option it is recommended to use scoped slots, which also don't require any special settings.