# React with Redux: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to follow a simple tutorial found on Udemy. For some reason the example code is working (probably because the tutorial is slightly out of date). I've done some googling about

Here is the output when trying to start the server.

```
ERROR in ./index.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (9:4)

   7 | function render(){
   8 |   ReactDOM.render(
>  9 |     <Examples/>,
     |     ^
  10 |     document.getElementById('root')  
  11 |   )
  12 | }

 @ multi main
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "redux",
  "version": "3.6.0",
  "description": "Predictable state container for JavaScript apps",
  "browser": "dist/redux.js",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "module": "es/index.js",
  "jsnext:main": "es/index.js",
  "typings": "./index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "lib",
    "es",
    "src",
    "index.d.ts"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf lib dist es coverage",
    "lint": "eslint src test build",
    "test": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=commonjs jest",
    "test:watch": "yarn test -- --watch",
    "test:cov": "yarn test -- --coverage",
    "build:commonjs": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=commonjs babel src --out-dir lib",
    "build:es": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=es babel src --out-dir es",
    "build:umd": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=es NODE_ENV=development rollup -c -i src/index.js -o dist/redux.js",
    "build:umd:min": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=es NODE_ENV=production rollup -c -i src/index.js -o dist/redux.min.js",
    "build": "yarn run build:commonjs && yarn run build:es && yarn run build:umd && yarn run build:umd:min",
    "prepublish": "yarn run clean && yarn run lint && yarn test && yarn run build && check-es3-syntax lib/ dist/ --kill --print",
    "examples:build": "babel-node examples/buildAll.js",
    "examples:lint": "eslint examples",
    "examples:test": "CI=true babel-node examples/testAll.js",
    "docs:clean": "rimraf _book",
    "docs:prepare": "gitbook install",
    "docs:build": "yarn run docs:prepare && gitbook build -g reactjs/redux && cp logo/apple-touch-icon.png _book/gitbook/images/apple-touch-icon-precomposed-152.png && cp logo/favicon.ico _book/gitbook/images",
    "docs:watch": "yarn run docs:prepare && gitbook serve",
    "docs:publish": "yarn run docs:clean && yarn run docs:build && cp CNAME _book && cd _book && git init && git commit --allow-empty -m 'update book' && git checkout -b gh-pages && touch .nojekyll && git add . && git commit -am 'update book' && git push git@github.com:reactjs/redux gh-pages --force"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/reactjs/redux.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "redux",
    "reducer",
    "state",
    "predictable",
    "functional",
    "immutable",
    "hot",
    "live",
    "replay",
    "flux",
    "elm"
  ],
  "authors": [
    "Dan Abramov <dan.abramov@me.com> (https://github.com/gaearon)",
    "Andrew Clark <acdlite@me.com> (https://github.com/acdlite)"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "http://redux.js.org",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.2.1",
    "lodash-es": "^4.2.1",
    "loose-envify": "^1.1.0",
    "symbol-observable": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.3.15",
    "babel-core": "^6.3.15",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-check-es2015-constants": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoped-functions": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-computed-properties": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-for-of": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-function-name": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-literals": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-object-super": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-parameters": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-shorthand-properties": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-spread": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-sticky-regex": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-template-literals": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-unicode-regex": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es3-member-expression-literals": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es3-property-literals": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-register": "^6.3.13",
    "check-es3-syntax-cli": "^0.1.1",
    "cross-env": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint": "^3.8.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^0.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.29.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "2.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.8.0",
    "gitbook-cli": "^2.3.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.1",
    "jest": "^18.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.3.4",
    "rollup": "^0.41.4",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^2.7.1",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-replace": "^1.1.1",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^1.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
    "typescript": "^1.8.0",
    "typescript-definition-tester": "0.0.4"
  },
  "npmName": "redux",
  "npmFileMap": [
    {
      "basePath": "/dist/",
      "files": [
        "*.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "loose-envify"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "testRegex": "(/test/.*\\.spec.js)$"
  }
}
```

Here is my webpack.config.js file:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: [ 'babel' ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: __dirname
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I did follow this answer in attempt to fix it: [babel-loader jsx SyntaxError: Unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460420/babel-loader-jsx-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

I did `npm install babel-preset-react` and added the query to my webpack.config file to look like:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: [ 'babel' ],
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      include: __dirname,
      query:
          {
              presets:['react']
          }
    }
  ]
}
```

}

However, this was the error I got after doing that:

```
$ npm start                                                                                                                           ‹ruby-2.3.0›

> redux-counter-example@0.0.0 start /Users/NAME/Documents/personal/redux-demo/Redux and React/React & Redux/v01-insert-redux
> node server.js

==>   Listening on port 3000. Open up http://localhost:3000/ in your browser.
/Users/NAME/Documents/personal/redux-demo/Redux and React/React & Redux/v01-insert-redux/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/LoadersList.js:54
    if(!element.loader || element.loader.indexOf("!") >= 0) throw new Error("Cannot define 'query' and multiple loaders in loaders list");
                                                            ^

Error: Cannot define 'query' and multiple loaders in loaders list
    at getLoadersFromObject (/Users/NAME/Documents/personal/redux-demo/Redux and React/React & Redux/v01-insert-redux/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/LoadersList.js:54:65)
    at LoadersList.<anonymous> (/Users/NAME/Documents/personal/redux-demo/Redux and React/React & Redux/v01-insert-redux/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/LoadersList.js:78:12)
    at Array.map (native)
    at LoadersList.match (/Users/NAME/Documents/personal/redux-demo/Redux and React/React & Redux/v01-insert-redux/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/LoadersList.js:70:19)
    at /Users/NAME/Documents/personal/redux-demo/Redux and React/React & Redux/v01-insert-redux/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:111:68
    at /Users/NAME/Documents/personal/redux-demo/Redux and React/React & Redux/v01-insert-redux/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:726:13
    at /Users/NAME/Documents/personal/redux-demo/Redux and React/React & Redux/v01-insert-redux/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at done (/Users/NAME/Documents/personal/redux-demo/Redux and React/React & Redux/v01-insert-redux/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:246:17)
    at /Users/NAME/Documents/personal/redux-demo/Redux and React/React & Redux/v01-insert-redux/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at /Users/NAME/Documents/personal/redux-demo/Redux and React/React & Redux/v01-insert-redux/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:723:17

npm ERR! Darwin 16.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node5/5.12.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v5.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! redux-counter-example@0.0.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the redux-counter-example@0.0.0 start script 'node server.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the redux-counter-example package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node server.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs redux-counter-example
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls redux-counter-example
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its evident from the error that you cannot define multiple `loaders` inside `loaders`, since you have declared `loaders`  inside `loaders` whereas it should be `loader` and assigned a single value. Also install and use babel-presets for `react`, `es2015` , `stage-0` if you use ES6 like

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
             presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
        },
        include: __dirname
      }
    ]
  }
```

Install the presets with

```
npm install -S babel-preset-react babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-stage-0
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. That solved my issue. I did read the `Cannot define 'query' and multiple loaders in loaders list` error but didn't really make the connection that I couldn't define multiple loaders because it's called `loaders` (plural) and they also mention "list". I'll make more of an effort to parse things in the future. Thank you for the help.

Comment: No problem glad to have helped