# Syntax error "Unexpected token" while following React + Node.js blog tutorial

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm following a [Site Point tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/building-a-react-universal-blog-app-a-step-by-step-guide/) to try to create a React app.

I'm stuck on these steps:

1. mkdir public
2. npm install
3. npm run developement

The first command will fail, since I already have a 'public' folder(?) with lots of resource folders and index.html.

npm install works just as expected.

npm run development runs into a syntax error:

```
ERROR in ./app-client.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (12:2)

  10 |
  11 | const Routes = (
> 12 |   <Router history={history}>
     |   ^
  13 |     { routes }
  14 |   </Router>
  15 | )
```

After copy-pasting everything for the nth time, I'm pretty sure there aren't any typos in app-client.js. Here it is:

```
// app-client.js
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router } from 'react-router'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'
const history = createBrowserHistory()

// Routes
import routes from './routes'

const Routes = (
  <Router history={history}>
    { routes }
  </Router>
)

const app = document.getElementById('app')
render(Routes, app)
```

And my folder structure is the same as in the tutorial:

```
package.json
public
  |-css
    |-bootstrap.min.css
    |-cosmic-custom.css
  |-js
    |-jquery.min.js
    |-bootstrap.min.js
    |-clean-blog.min.js
views
  |-index.html
webpack.config.js
```

Which also makes me quite puzzled as to why I would run "mkdir public" here?

I tried renaming files to have a .jsx ending; that didn't work. Additionally, this is my webpack.conf.js file:

```
// webpack.config.js
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: './app-client.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public/dist',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/dist/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loaders: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.jsx$/, loaders: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/, query: {presets: ['es2015', 'react']} }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.COSMIC_BUCKET': JSON.stringify(process.env.COSMIC_BUCKET),
      'process.env.COSMIC_READ_KEY': JSON.stringify(process.env.COSMIC_READ_KEY),
      'process.env.COSMIC_WRITE_KEY': JSON.stringify(process.env.COSMIC_WRITE_KEY)
    })
 ]
};
```

Comment: have you got `.babelrc` ? share your `webpack.config` file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [babel-loader jsx SyntaxError: Unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460420/babel-loader-jsx-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

Comment: @Aaqib dont think so, i should? also added conf file :)

Comment: @TomFenech didnt help, not sure i did it right tho... this whole react things seems confusing af

Comment: @Aaqib because thats how it was in tutorial... i will try that now! this whole React seems VERY confusing to start with. been working as web-dev for 2 years and android dev 2y, but react? ahhahhah

Comment: @Aaqib still same error.. updated conf with whats on the question now, then ran npm install and npm run developement. Got same error

Comment: Rename your React files to extension *.jsx

Comment: @AndréWerlang soo webpack.conf and routes? app-client.js looks like basic js to me, so others but not app-client?

Comment: @AndréWerlang still same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `webpack.config.js` you need to modify your loaders,

**Firstly**, instead of two times including the same loader, include only one time.

**Secondly**, instead of using loaders inside loaders array use `loader` without `s`.

Like below:

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ }
    ]
  }
```

And **finally** install babel-preset-stage-0, babel-preset-react, es2015  as a development dependency like `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0 babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react`, and use an inside query Object like this:

```
   module: {
        loaders: [
          { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/,
           query: {presets: ['stage-0','es2015', 'react']} }
        ]
      }
```

Preferably the other way is creating `.babelrc` file instead of query inside `webpack.config.js` in the root (where your `webpack.config.js`) is and then including the code below:

```
{presets: ['stage-0','es2015', 'react']}
```

If all of this is overwhelming, the best place to start [React](https://reactjs.org/) without worrying about any dependency or other issues is [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app).

Comment: Oh my god! Granted, i started with too hard project for beginner. but atleast i got this working now! will go to tutorial you pointed, lots of thanks!

Comment: Glad to help you  :)