# Im trying to import a jsx file into another jsx file but im getting an syntax error

Tags: reactjs, import, jsx

I'm learning ReactJS and I am trying to import a .jsx file . into another .jsx file.

I have added this to import a file:

```
import Users from "./Users";
```

But I am getting a `SyntaxError Unexpected identifier` error, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: do you use webpack?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [babel-loader jsx SyntaxError: Unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460420/babel-loader-jsx-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

Comment: hey, Thanks for replying. I just created a mvc project and added reactjs to it. I don't know if its babel as my jsx converts into js ok. just the import statement isn't converted/replaced with converted js from the other jsx file. hope that makes sense !