# Reactjs can not get it to work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi guys i am new to Reactjs and i can not get it to work.

First i got the [unexpected token error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905227/reactjs-unexpected-token-error) that most reactjs starters have encountered, after reading the suggested solutions

- i took all react js code and put it in a separate .js file like below

  ```
  <script src="include_js/react.js" type="text/jsx"></script>
  ```
- than i added the suggested comments on top of the file

  ```
  /** @jsx React.DOM */

  ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello</h1>,
    document.getElementById('indicators')
  );
  ```

The error is gone but i think react.js is'nt executed at all `<h1>Hello</h1>` is not added to "indicators" div. I see it is downloaded in network tab but not listed in source tab(Chrome Dev Tools)

**NOTE:** I have added both required plugins beforehand

```
    <script src="react-0.14.8.min.js"></script>
    <script src="react-dom-0.14.8.min.js"></script>
```

**SOLVED**
I changed `type="text/jsx"` to `type="text/babel"` also included `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>` as [@kujira](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5911613/kujira) mentioned. I also removed `/** @jsx React.DOM */` as it is not needed anymore

Comment: Did you try the solutions suggested in the question you linked?  Looks like your scripts are not using type="text/babel".  The pragma you added to the top of your file is outdated; see his edit http://stackoverflow.com/a/20913732/4206756 which says it's no longer needed in react 0.12+ (you seem to be using 0.14.8).

Comment: I think have also tried type="text/babel" but i am not totally sure, i will give it a try. thnx

Comment: Make sure to add babel plugin: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>` if using `type="text/babel"`

Comment: I see, is there any alternative way if you don't want to add an extra plugin(babel), i think i read somewhere that it was not required

Comment: It is not required if you transform the JSX into JS beforehand. This plugin does it on the fly.