# ReactJS randomly Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unexpected-token

Project was created with create-react-app. Did not eject. There are no webpack configs. Default `"react-scripts": "^3.4.0"`. On `dev` version there is no error. But on production when user stays long on one page and clicks the link it shows white page, and after updating the site(deploying new version). This error randomly appears. Output on console

> Unexpected token '<'

and no other information.

There is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "description",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@bugsnag/js": "^6.5.0",
    "@bugsnag/plugin-react": "^6.5.0",
    "@glidejs/glide": "^3.4.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.4.1",
    "@sentry/browser": "^5.11.2",
    "@sentry/cli": "^1.49.0",
    "@types/jest": "^25.1.3",
    "@types/node": "^13.7.4",
    "@types/rc-switch": "^1.9.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.22",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.5",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.1",
    "classnames": "2.2.6",
    "debounce-promise": "^3.1.2",
    "formik": "^1.5.8",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "logrocket": "^1.0.6",
    "logrocket-react": "^4.0.1",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.27",
    "orgchart": "^2.1.5",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "purgecss": "^1.4.0",
    "rc-switch": "^1.9.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-autosuggest": "^9.4.3",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.7.6",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.0.2",
    "react-contextmenu": "^2.11.0",
    "react-data-export": "^0.6.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.9.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dropzone-component": "^3.2.0",
    "react-intl": "2.4.0",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.3",
    "react-redux": "7.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.0",
    "react-select": "^3.0.4",
    "react-select-async-paginate": "^0.3.10",
    "react-table": "latest",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.3.0",
    "reactstrap": "^8.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.5",
    "styled-components": "^5.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.1.2",
    "typescript": "^3.8.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.15.5",
    "yup": "^0.27.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "yarn run tailwind && react-scripts start",
    "build": "yarn run tailwind && node ./purge-tailwindcss.js && cross-env react-scripts build",
    "tailwind": "./node_modules/.bin/tailwind build ./src/assets/css/vendor/tailwind.base.css -c ./tailwind.js -o ./src/assets/css/vendor/tailwind.css",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=node",
    "crt": "bash create-component.sh",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint src/**/*.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.18.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
  }
}
```

Comment: [Reactjs: Unexpected token '<' Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905227/reactjs-unexpected-token-error?rq=1) did you refer this link, if its helpful let me know

Comment: @pavankumar yes I checked. And I tried to change like ```type = "text/babel"``` but it's not solution. And other answers includes webpack improvement. But I use react-script for build

Comment: did you try `type="text/jsx"` as your script type?

Comment: @pavankumar I tried it too. create-react-app doesn't add any types on build for scripts.

Comment: Did you check compatibility between node version and react-scripts on production

Comment: @AravindAnil my node version on server 13.7. And on my laptop 10.15. I use last version of react-scripts. I think it compatible. On [site](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/) written that we should use Node >= 8.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know how. But after enabling `sourcemap` this error doesn't shown.
I removed this command from `yarn build`:

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
```