# How do i solve unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, use-context

I am creating a toast package using react hook (useContext) but it was working in app until published and im getting unexpected token [1]

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBOpk.png

Comment: Hi Victor, make sure to provide code in the question if you want some help. Also, add code that is not the problem but might be involved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reactjs: Unexpected token '<' Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905227/reactjs-unexpected-token-error)