# Unexpected token while using modal in react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap4-modal

Running into an compilation error while trying to create a sidebar using react-bootsrtrap modal.
here is my code:

```js
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import "./style.css";

export default class Sidebar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Modal className='menu-sidebar left' show={this.props.isVisible} onHide={this.props.onHide} autoFocus keyboard>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>Menu</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    {this.props.children}
                </Modal.Body>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}
```

The error while compilation i get is:

```
./node_modules/react-bootstrap-sidebar/sidebar.js
SyntaxError: /home/wd/Projects/dxc_dashboard/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sidebar/sidebar.js: Unexpected token (9:12)

   7 |     render() {
   8 |         return (
>  9 |             <Modal className='menu-sidebar left' show={this.props.isVisible}  autoFocus keyboard>
     |             ^
  10 |                 <Modal.Header closeButton>
  11 |                     <Modal.Title>Menu</Modal.Title>
  12 |                 </Modal.Header>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905227/reactjs-unexpected-token-error