# Error adding React with HTML page,Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have added a React functional component with existing HTML page, getting a strange error : *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'*

HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <div id="like_button_container"></div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.8/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

    <!-- Load our React component. -->
    <script src="like_button.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

connected JS

```
"use strict";

function Like_button() {
  const [like, setLike] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      {like ? <p>you liked t</p> : null}
      <button onClick={() => setLike(true)}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
}


const domContainer = document.querySelector("#like_button_container");
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Like_button), domContainer);
```

[image]

Comment: perhaps error with React version

Comment: what is the `=` at the top of the html file doing?

Comment: Actually a typo during copy paste

Comment: Add `type = "text/babel"`or `text/jsx` to the `<script>`

Answer (score 1):

trying replacing this in the html:

from:

`<script src="like_button.js"></script>`

to:

`<script type="text/jsx" src="./like_button.js"></script>`

you need to tell it to use `jsx`

Comment: So it's an exact duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33481482/5625547) answer?

Comment: ah yes I guess so! I hadn't seen that answer before

Comment: shall we vote to close?

Comment: Yeah, of course

Comment: Encountered new error,Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/dell/Desktop/try/like_button.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: @AnoopKGeorge we should close this question as it is a duplicate and you should ask a new question if you are getting a new error

Comment: ok, I will close it

Answer (score 1):

first, you should add babel-core CDN.

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>`
then add `text/babel` to your script like this:

```
<div id="like_button_container"></div>
<script type="text/babel" src="./like_button.js"></script>
```