# Parsing error: JSX expressions must have one parent element

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm importing these two components, but this error appears, the page keeps loading normally, but I don't know how to solve this.

```
<DesktopNav />
<MobileNav />
```

I already did with

```
<React.Fragment>
<DesktopNav />
<MobileNav />
</React.Fragment>
```

Or

```
<div>
<DesktopNav />
<MobileNav />
</div>
```

The error 'JSX expressions must have one parent element.' no longer appears, but when I load the page it shows an error `` Unexpected token `>`. ``

Comment: To get an exact solution you have to share more code otherwise it is tough for some who try to fix it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905227/reactjs-unexpected-token-error